# slow jquery performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 200 small icons (4kb) on my web page
on click on a menu i want the icons to dim out 
im using this function

```
if (which!="all")
{                                   
    $(function () {
        // SET OPACITY  TO 20%
        $("."+which).stop().animate({opacity: '0.2'}, 100);
    });
}
```

for some reason the performance is very slow and it takes a long time for the icons to dim out
How can i speed up the performance ?

thanks

Comment: It may be because you are trying to animate too many DOM elements at once. How does it perform if you only select one of the icons?

I was experimenting with something similar the other night. I was dynamically adding 100+ divs to my DOM and Firefox started to crawl. I wasn't event trying to animate them

Answer (score 2):

You can animate opacity with CSS3. As long as that's an option within your requirements, I would advise looking into CSS3 for this kind of animation instead of JS.

Comment: I didn't know CCS3 could do that. A quick google search returned this page of demos. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animations/

Comment: well to be honest im quite surprised as well to learn that css3 can do that - this is amazing

Comment: unfortunately most of the world is still working with IE9 - so i will lose a lot of audience - any other thoughts of how i can do that more quickly ?

Comment: There are good answers below: Andy's is great if the icons are in a "collector" container of some sort. You could find really clever ways to kludge something together if you had to; I can imagine 2 cloned divs, 1 has the text set to the same colour as the background; 1 has the images set to be invisible. Then the div with the images gets faded out. But thing is: it's a hack. The non-hack version is to simply "hide" without graceful animation when CSS3 support is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture a guess and say that the poor performance is changing the DOM properties of 200 items a lot of times per second over and over (mouse over right?)

You should consider a more DOM-friendly approach, like `<canvas>` and drawing your view manually.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to dim all the icons at once, you could try dimming the parent container instead of each individual icon.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) -- basically one large image "sliced" into 200 small pieces.

Then you can create a second large image, exactly like the first, but dimmed out -- and use JavaScript/jQuery to swap one image for the other at every instance.

If nothing else, this should improve your page load times considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to cache the icon objects in an array and loop over them. 
Or use css to change opacity.